# alarm clock app with notification on lock screen

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, alarm

In the past active alarms from the default app showed up on the lock screen (time and date). This feature seems to be gone in 4.1.2. Does it work in later versions of Android? Can it be done somehow with an external app?

Comment: Which handset are you using?

Comment: There are tons of lock screen widgets you could try, but I find [Dash Clock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.nurik.roman.dashclock&hl=en) to be the best. It can display (amongst other things the upcoming alarm(s))

Comment: Yes, I found Dash Clock myself, but it's for Android 4.2+.